# How to modify the spaces in a text file to tabulate it with Excel "Text Import Wizard"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editors

I have a text file with 6 columns of values, separated by spaces. However, those spaces do not have consistent patterns. So is there a quicker way to tabulate it?

You can see below that sometimes there is one space in the beginning, sometimes not; sometimes there are two spaces together but sometimes there is only one space.

```
 0.0234228 -0.0011518 -0.0108913 -0.0182157  0.0207903 -0.0185184
 -0.0289417 -0.00151549  -0.0168961   0.0314295  -0.0440188   0.0131252
0.00516397  0.0246989 0.00290842 -0.0194605 0.00117188  0.0563778
-0.00369979 -0.00689284   0.0101913   0.0247507   0.0555183   0.0297872
 0.00128166  -0.0294381   0.0149216   0.0306846   0.0148319 -0.00984549
-0.00999997 -0.00069907   0.0143736   0.0155811   -0.034015  -0.0301285
 -0.0461045 -0.00544453  -0.0241729  -0.0493851   0.0471825  -0.0267914
 -0.0270271  -0.0173604 -0.00740417  -0.0193481  0.00750086   0.0106742
  0.0283322 6.10918e-05  -0.0293541   0.0105264 -0.00201288  -0.0269939
```

Comment: What about a bit of Powershell, e.g. `foreach($line in Get-Content input.txt) {(($line.trim()) -replace '\s+', ' ') | Out-File -append output.txt}`.  Open a Powershell command prompt in the same directory as the `input.txt`, paste the above to run it and then you should have `output.txt`.

Comment: How about using Find feature in Excel and replace double space to one space first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Copy and paste the entire text file into an Excel document. Use the `TRIM` function to remove all extra spaces, i.e. only leaving one space between words.
   [image]
2. Select the column with the trimmed data (Column B), hit Ctrl-C to copy it, then Paste it as Values by going to "Home" -> "Clipboard" -> "Paste" - dropdown arrow -> "Values".

[image]

3. Then, with column B selected, use the "Text to Columns" command (found under "Data" -> "Data Tools") to split the data into columns, selecting Space as the delimiter.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for using TRIM. Just apply the "Text to Columns" Function right after copy&pasting the text to Excel the first time.
Just make sure you select the "Treat consecutive delimiters as one" option, as shown above.